# Targeting specific UIViewController instance between duplicated UIViewsControllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController (cardView) that has a view counter. There is a button, "Menu", on the upper right to open a separate UIViewController (cardsViewer) that lists of all different cards and opens as a modal.

Inside of cardsViewer, you can click one of the buttons on the list and it overlays a modal of the same type of UIViewController (cardView) and displays the same view counter but instead of the "Menu" button, is has a "Back" button.

The problem is when I go to that new instance of the cardView, if it is the same one as the original one, the view counter updates on that second instance of cardView, but when you back out to the original cardView and send it (through a delegate function) the updated viewCount, it doesn't update the label on the refresh.

I even have the delegate function print the view count showing that it is received but it doesn't do anything to the view. This occurs even after the second instance of the view is dismissed but the first still does not update.

It's almost like, as soon as I make that second instance, I can no longer modify the UI on the first instance. I used dispatch get main queue and all of that, but it was to no avail.

Help!

Comment: You need to show some code; It seems that you aren't keeping the right references to the view controller instances.

Comment: @Paulw11 Uh oh, I should be keeping some kind of reference to the first one?

Comment: A view controller is no different to an array or a dictionary or any other object. You can have multiple instances and you need to refer to the appropriate instance

Comment: @Paulw11, in my short time developing for iOS, I have not encountered having to reference individual views. Thank you for letting me know! Do you have any good resources for getting started on specific referencing?

Comment: A 'reference' is just a variable.

Comment: This was happening to me as well. I am using a UITabBarController in my application and whenever i tried to update the UI on one of my views, thru a delegate function, it wasnt working. Drove me crazy, until I realized that the problem was being caused by  referencing the wrong instance of a view controller. You simply need to somehow hold a reference to the view that you wish to update. The reference must point to the SAME instance of that view, NOT a copy. Since classes are copied, this is why you are having this issue. Would be happy to dig into your code further if you don't mind posting.

Comment: The code is a bit of a mess at this moment. Is there a super simple example that you could show how to generally reference a specific instance of a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example for you per request.

In my app, I am using an audio player to stream remote audio files. And a `UITabBarController` to hold and present my views. I have a table view of songs inside my `SongsViewController`. When a row is tapped, 2 things happen... 1) the UI segues to a new view controller, my `NowPlayingViewController` and 2) a call is made to my `ControllerClass`, which handles getting the song from the specified URL, and beginning playback. I needed the delegate for my `ControllerClass`to be the `NowPlayingViewController` so that when the song finished loading, I could send an update to the UI on the `NowPlayingViewController`. So, inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPathMethod` of the `SongsViewController`i did this ...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //get a reference to the NowPlayingViewController, and set it as the delegate to the ControllerClass

    let nowPlayingVC = NowPlayingViewController()
    ControllerClass.delegate = nowPlayingVC
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

BUT! when the `ControllerClass` executed its delegate callback to the `NowPlayingVC`, nothing happened on the UI! After some banging my head on the wall... I figured out that the reason this wasn't working was because:
 When a song was tapped, the tab bar controller was presenting an instance of the `NowPlayingViewController` which it already held a reference to. And when a song was tapped I would also grab ANOTHER REFERENCE to the `NowPlayingViewController` and I then used that instance (reference) to set as the delegate to my `ControllerClass`. This was a problem because the instance of the `NowPlayingViewController` that was held by my tab bar controller was a DIFFERENT instance of the `NowPlayingViewController` than the one that I had referenced and set as the delegate to my `ControllerClass` . This meant that when the `ControllerClass` went to callback to the `NowPlayingViewController` it was calling back to a different instance than the one that had been presented by the tab bar controller! Thus i didnt see any changes happening to the UI like they were supposed to.

In my case, since i was using a `UITabBarController` I was able to do this ...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //find the instance of the NowPlayingViewController that is being presented, the one that i am VIEWING and set that instacne as the delegate to the ControllerCLass

    let nowPlayingVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! NowPlayingVC
    ControllerClass.delegate = nowPlayingVC

 }
```

By accessing the view controllers that were held inside the tab bar, I was able to grab a reference to the SAME instance of the `NowPlayingViewController` that was the one that was being presented, and thus the `ControllerClass`, upon calling back to its delegate, was properly calling back to the instance of the `NowPlayingViewController` that had been presented by the tab bar controller.

I assume you are not using a UITabBarController, but your solution will still be to reference the SAME instance of your VC and be sure to use that one instance in both places! Just make sure to reference the SAME instance.

Comment: Thanks @MikeG, crazy nice explanation. Very much appreciated! I just need to digest it and get something similar going in mine. Will update when I give it a go!

Comment: Very welcome, take your time, let me know if anything is unclear i am happy to help you solve your issue! I am very new to iOS dev myself, so I know what it is like ! Drawing this out on paper would be a huge help to you I highly recommend it. It is a lengthy explanation but it is truly quite simply if you can just visualize it

Comment: Update: @MikeG, your thinking led me in the right direction on how to approach references. Although I did not follow exactly what you did, it helped me in taking the direction of instead storing the instance in a struct and calling it when needed. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! That was the hope. Good luck